# Двоеточие в сложном предложении

Tags: двоеточие

Какой знак препинания вы поставили бы на месте вопроса в следующем предложении?

*А вот Сергей Николаевич сразу понравился дворнику (?) было в нем что-то душевное от народа и от братства священного, не было в нём этой гнили, что погубила Старую Москву и теперь на её костях строила Новую АнтиМоскву из металла, стекла и бетона.*

У Розенталя написано, что если второе предложение БСП выражает причину того, о чём говорится в первом, нужно ставить двоеточие. А возможны ли ещё какие-то варианты?

UPD: Только что прочитала в комментарии Sharon, что возможны варианты. Поставили бы здесь тире?

Comment: Здесь только двоеточие с интонационным предупреждением (понижение голоса перед значительно увеличенной паузой). Вторая часть очень подробно раскрывает содержание первой. Ведь  указание причины – это тоже как бы раскрытие темы. Фактически здесь два БЛОКА, так как вторая часть тоже сложная конструкция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***А вот Сергей Николаевич сразу понравился дворнику:** // было в нем что-то душевное от народа и от братства священного, не было в нём этой гнили, что погубила Старую Москву и теперь на её костях строила Новую АнтиМоскву из металла, стекла и бетона.*

1. Это сложное синтаксическое целое [Полный академический справочник под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)

§ 132. В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся на **крупные логико-синтаксические блоки,** которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, на стыке блоков ставятся **знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков**, при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании:

2. Предложение делится на **две части (два блока)**, на стыке блоков нужно поставить **двоеточие** с интонационным предупреждением (понижение голоса перед значительно увеличенной паузой). Вторая часть **очень подробно** раскрывает содержание первой. (Ведь указание причины – это тоже как бы раскрытие темы.)

**Тире** для этой цели не подойдет: здесь пояснительный характер отношений, а не присоединительный, как у тире.

Примечание. Анализ примеров по теме можно посмотреть [здесь](https://proza.ru/2023/03/12/1248)

Comment: *Тире для этой цели не подойдет: здесь пояснительный характер отношений, а не присоединительный, как у тире* — за это респект, не ожидал.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за объяснение и примеры!